# VB.NET reading xlsx file gives not a valid path

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection

I can't seem to read a .xlsx file using the following connection string:

**Webconfig**

```
<add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"/>
```

**Code File**

```
conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel07ConString").ConnectionString

Dim connExcel As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
connExcel.Open()
```

I have been getting this error:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)". OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "'F:\Ishan\Projects\ImportExcel2DB\ImportExcel2DB\Files\Whole Extract.xlsx' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.".

and yes there is file at this specific location. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the connection string you have `{0}` and `{1}`. What values are you passing to those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HDR needs to be either Yes or No.  See my project below

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim reader As New CSVReader()
        Dim ds As DataSet = reader.ReadCSVFile("filename", True)
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class CSVReader

    Public Function ReadCSVFile(ByVal fullPath As String, ByVal headerRow As Boolean) As DataSet

        Dim path As String = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        Dim filename As String = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

        Dim header As String
        If headerRow Then
            header = "Yes"
        Else
            header = "No"
        End If

        Try
            If File.Exists(fullPath) Then

                Dim ConStr As String = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\""", path, header)
                Dim SQL As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename)
                Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr)
                adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile")
                ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Table1"
            End If
            For Each col As DataColumn In ds.Tables("Table1").Columns
                col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_")
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return ds
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Hi JD, i was expecting answers in VB.net!